# JOptionPane Message with File Path

Tags: java, swing, file, path, joptionpane

Is there a way to put a filepath into a `JOptionPane`?

E.g. I have a folder in my project directory and would like to get the path to that folder and show it into the message.

Comment: By 'filepath' DYM a string like `C:\Users\Andrew\FractalTerrain.png`?

Comment: Have you tried passing a `File` object as the message parameter?

Comment: Please make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), thank you

Comment: As an aside, the option pane can display anything that is an `Object` so it obviously can display a 'filepath' object.  It then comes down to, will it render it *as you expect?*

Comment: @andrew-thompson Yes, the filepath should look like that string. But how do I read the filepath in case the directory changes?

Comment: *"But how do I read the filepath"*  What DYM by 'read'?  How do you 'read' it now?  BTW - I think you are making the mistake of presuming that your 'folders' (all directories really) will be accessible to the end user.  That is typically *not* the case.  If you want the user to have direct access to application resources, it will be necessary to extract them from the Jar they are in and put them somewhere on the local file system.  A sub-directory of `user.home` is a good place, and is easy to reproduce whenever the app. needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your file path,remember to use double slahses instead of single ones");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, is there a way to put in a file path by variable? E.g. in case the path changes I don't want to manually change it in the message.

Comment: hmm it should wokr the same hey...just instead of the string literal you use a string variable

Comment: String filepath="your file path,remember to use double slahses instead of single ones";                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,filepath);

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I just tried it and it works fine, thank you my friend!